# Recommendations for introductory open source projects for a second-year computer science student proficient in Python and Java

Tags: python, java, open-source

I am a second-year computer science major looking to contribute to open source projects. I have some proficiency in Python and Java and have researched various sites such as SourceForge and Apache, but I find the project listings on those sites to have a steep learning curve.

Can anyone recommend some introductory open source projects that would be suitable for my level of programming skills and could potentially lead to contributions to bigger projects? I am open to any recommendations on this topic and would greatly appreciate any advice or insights.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't ask at your campus? At mine there are plenty of projects from and for students. That's the first step to go. Some projects also use opensource projects and manipulate them. So you only learn a bit of the opensource project. And for the next step many students contribute to the opensource projects that were used in the students projects.

Answer (score 2):

Most open source projects need better documentation. You could pick one that you like and work on improving the documentation as you learn about the project. If you learn to write good documentation, that's a good career skill. And as you write it, you begin to learn enough about that project to work on the code before long.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in contributing to Python , you can submit documentation and testing related patches in the beginning. Here are the steps on how to contribute. https://openhatch.org/wiki/Contributing_to_Python.

It can also help you in applying for Google Summer of Code and other Python projects.

Answer (score 1):

Check out some projects that interest you ... to get an idea of what kind of projects to get involved in.

Here are some broad suggestions:
1) Have you heard of [Google Summer of Code](https://code.google.com/soc/)? 
2) You could set up your own project in [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/account/login.php?return_to=/account/), or some other repository. 
3) You could check out what others are doing and get involved in their projects. Check out projects in SF, [Freecode](http://freecode.com/), or [Google Code](https://code.google.com/).

Don't put your coding ability down, put it to use. Projects can always use people for doing documentation as well. CHEERS, and happy coding to you!

Here's [one more link](http://opensource.com/life/13/1/10-ways-get-started-open-source) that I saw today, and it reminded me of your question. The link suggests ten things you can do to be involved in open source.